# Capture function parameter passed to a function as bare symbols in javascript

Tags: javascript

I like to write a function that take a dot dot dot argument, captures the elements passed as symbol, and them as string.

Is it possible to pass these ...args as symbols, and to capture the inputs of the function?

To be clear, I'd like to write this:

```
function myFunc(...args) {
  // capture the ...args 
};
myFunc(a, b, c);
["a", "b", "c"]
```

#### backstory

In R, you can use lazy evaluation and capture a symbol passed to a function without evaluating it, and turn it into a string:

```r
library(rlang)
x <- function(...){
  p <- quos(...)
  sapply(p, quo_name)
}

> x(a, b)        
"a" "b" 

> x(c, def, ghijk)
"c"   "def" "ghijk"
```

This is what I would like to reproduce in JavaScript. Is that doable?

Comment: I mean, what is even the point of this? Can't you put double quotes around the values you are passing and be done with it?

Comment: JavaScript, like *many* other languages, treats the parameters in a function call as expressions to be evaluated. Even when an expression is just a naked reference to a variable, the expression is evaluated and the *value* is passed to the function. That's true in all cases.

Comment: @AvinKavish I know I can do this. I'm exploring JS metaprogramming capabilities based on what I know of metaprogramming in other languages. 
The way it is used it in R is for example when you want to extract a column from a dataframe. A "quote" is a character variable, a symbol is a column. So filter(df, column == "char"), not filter(df, "column" == "char").

Comment: @Pointy thanks. I was under the impression that parameters were not always evaluated, as for exemple you can run a function with a param that's never evaluated and it work : function myFunc(a) { return(1 + 2) };myFunc(); doesn't throw any error for example.

Comment: @ColinFAY well JavaScript is dumb about that; it *always* evaluates parameter expressions. Try that function call with an expression that is syntactically correct but has a runtime error (like an `undefined` property reference or something). It has to evaluate the parameter expressions because they might have side effects.

Comment: @Pointy ok, thanks! I guess what I'm trying to achieve is not doable after all :)

Comment: It's actually possible. You have to pass a function

Comment: @Pointy Ah, I see where the confusion arose from, I posted the comment above after you posted yours. I was actually replying to his reply to my initial comment and my answer was a partial answer solely addressing the use case in the comment.

Comment: Colin, this might interest you, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this as expressed in the question. One way that's close is to pass in an object with the keys named for the variables. The syntax it's pretty close to what you're already doing:

```js
function myFunc(args) {
    console.log(Object.keys(args))

};
let a = 1;
let b = 2;
let c = 3;

myFunc({a, b, c});
```

Of course, if you are just trying to get the strings `"a" "b" "c"`, you should just pass in the strings.

Answer (score 4):

No.

The *values* of the variables are passed to the function. It never sees the variable names you copied them from.

Answer (score 1):

> The way it is used it in R is for example when you want to extract a column from a dataframe. A "quote" is a character variable, a symbol is a column. So filter(df, column == "char"), not filter(df, "column" == "char").

The syntax you presented can be reproduced quite closely, `filter(df, column == "char")` I'm not sure exactly what the structure of the dataframe is nor what the filtering logic is but in your example the second argument is essentially a predicate and predicates can be written in JavaScript using arrow functions, like so.

```
function filter(obj, predicate) {
  predicate(obj) // <--- apply the predicate to the object
}

filter(df, obj => obj.column === "char")
```

Comment: How does this have anything to do with the question posted here? How would you get the example output the OP asks for?

Comment: That's not what he is looking for, if you read the comments section he mentions that the syntax he is trying to replicate is `filter(df, column == "char")`.

Comment: Right, so how exactly would you get your code to print out the names of variables passed to a function?

Comment: From what I understand that's a contrived example, he is not actually looking to print them on screen. The actual use case is mentioned to be "The way it is used it in R is for example when you want to extract a column from a dataframe." and he proceeds to show a predicate `column == "char"`. In Js we do actually write predicates as arrow functions just not with symbols.

Comment: Thanks. That indeed doesn't answer the original question but that's definitely useful. Thanks again to you both, I will dig into this.